# Document Expired after back button on WebSphere Web App

Tags: websphere, was

I am trying to understand the cause of Document Expired message from Browser when I return a page through the back button, I already performed some tests using Cache-Control with max-age and expires with max_value, but have not yet succeeded, has anyone encountered this situation with WebSphere ? Is there any cache configuration of file of WebSphere to manage the cache for web pages ?

Comment: Was the page loaded by HTTP POST or GET? Have you tried different browsers and they all behave the same? Have you confirmed at the _browser_ (via developer tools) that the cache headers are what you have the server sending? For instance, it's possible that proxies between the browser and server are also affecting the cache headers.

Comment: Do you have more details about proxies between the browser and server ? I'm using post and was tested with the same issue for all browsers

Comment: I'm just saying to look at the browser tools and verify that the response headers you see in the browser are the exact same ones you're expecting to see, that you sent from the web app.